# Passing block as an argument

Tags: ruby

What is the correct way to pass a block among other arguments to a method in Ruby? I have this code:

```
def Foo(arg1, &block1)
  puts arg1
  block1.call
end
```

And this doesn't work:

```
Foo('hello', { puts 'world' })
```

Comment: A block is not an argument, so it cannot be put inside the parentheses for arguments. You have to put it outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
Foo('hello') { puts 'world' }
#hello
#world
```

Also note method names should be all lowercase (and snake_cased).

Comment: Related to this, is it possible to do more than one block parameter? Or even two block parameters with a third non-block parameter?

Comment: @Aaron I don't know if you can. You can use [procs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Proc.html) and pass them to your method. Not sure if this is idiomatic but something like: `proc1 = Proc.new { puts "proc1" }; def bar(proc_one); proc_one.call; end; bar(proc1) #=> proc1`. You can define your method to accept multiple procs or 'non-proc' arguments in any order. Might be helpful, or at steer you in the right (I hope) direction.

Comment: __Also note method names should be all lowercase__ - false (but suggested by some style guides). There are a lot of methods in Ruby like `Array()`, `Float()`, `Hash()` etc.

Comment: @AaronThomas `Enumerable#find` takes an optional proc which is called when no matching element is found, e.g. `[1, 2, 3].find -> { -1 } { |i| i > 3 } #=> -1`